# Selenium Unable to Locate Element of "Compose Email" Button

Tags: python, selenium, gmail

I have been using Python to send Gmails with good progress. Unfortunately, Selenium is having problems identifying the "compose" button that allows a user to write and send an email to people.

```
from selenium import webdriver
your_email = input("Email:")
your_password = input("Password:")
if "@cps.edu" in your_email:
    your_email_two = your_email.replace("@cps.edu","")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Shitty Horrible Pc/PycharmProjects/learningpython/pytjom/chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
driver.get("https://gmail.com")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
element.send_keys(your_email)
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("VfPpkd-RLmnJb")
element.click()
element = driver.find_element_by_id("identification")
element.send_keys(your_email_two)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("ember489")
element.send_keys(your_password)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("authn-go-button")
element.click()
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("VfPpkd-RLmnJb")
element.click()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("T-I T-I-KE L3")
element.click()
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".T-I T-I-KE L3"}
```

I have tried maximizing the tab, telling Selenium to wait before attempting to locate the element -- all to no avail. I have also looked into other posts above similar issues and not much has helped. Should I try removing the spaces in the class name? Is there anything else I can do?

[Picture of Gmail with compose button and the element type + name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0VtS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my issue by using the older HTML version of Gmail.("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/s32qz81kdosc/?zy=h&f=1")

The code to identify the "Compose Email" element and press it:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Compose Mail")
element.click()
```

You can add implicit or explicit waits if you want.